# What language has the longest word for 'no' and 'yes'?

Tags: cross-linguistic, language-change, psycholinguistics

I'm asking this because I'm learning Swahili now, for which the word 'yes' translates to 'ndiyo' and 'no' translates to 'hakuna.'  It strikes me as strange that a language would have such long words to convey such important concepts as 'yes' and 'no.'

Two questions:

1. Are there any other languages that have longer words than Swahili for yes and no (or any  basic modifiers or conjunctions)?
2. What is the reason that such long words stayed in the language, rather than evolving into an abridged version of the word?

**Edit**:
The intention of my post was to see if other languages had long words for "yes" and "no" when directly translated.  I'm not concerned about other ways to communicate 'yes' and 'no' (like 'affirmative' or 'negative') because those aren't the default responses to questions in the language under consideration.  The follow-up question was why these languages have such large words for default responses (yes or no) when it would seem like the words should evolve over time to be more efficient (shorter amount of time to say, write, etc.)

Comment: I'm leaving this only because of the question number 2. :P While there is no hard rule to this, please try to answer to both questions in your answer.

Comment: English has 'affirmative' and 'negative', four and three syllables respectively. Swahili 'yes' doesn't seem long to me, it's only two syllables, a common length.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I think the OP meant the actual corresponding expressions for "yes"... In Finnish they say *kyllä*, but I think we are going to find longer stuff.

Comment: _yes_ in Telugu is conveyed by the trisyllabic _avunu_.

Comment: @Alenanno they **are** actual corresponding expressions. But assuming you're correct about the OPs intention, a better way to ask this question would be 'what language has the longest monomorphemic words for "no" and for "yes" '.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut The OP said "..., for which the word 'yes' translates to 'ndiyo'". It's clearly asking for the words "yes" and "no" and not for expressions/words conveying the same message. :) If you think it needs improving, feel free to edit!

Comment: @Alenanno I'm sure that 'affirmative' also translates to 'ndiyo' in Swahili--I'm not sure how 'words for "yes" and "no" ' are different from '...expressions/words conveying the same message'? Anyway, I'm a bit uncertain about editing it in the way I suggest as it changes it quite a bit, and it uses linguistic terminology in a way that may not be immediately clear. I'd prefer to wait and see what Parseltongue thinks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it counts but Mandarin Chinese doesn't have "yes" or "no" words so in order to say "yes" they literally repeat the verb. A negetive response would be saying "not <verb>" (sometimes shortened to just "not"). While some verbs in Mandarin can be a single syllable long, other can be more. http://mandarin.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/yes_no.htm

Comment: Wow... didn't expect this to escalate.  The intention of my post was to see if other languages had long words for "yes" and "no" when directly translated.  I'm not concerned about other ways to communicate 'yes' and 'no' (like 'affirmative' or 'negative') because those aren't the default responses to questions in the language under consideration.  The follow-up question was why these languages have such large words for default responses (yes or no) when it would seem like the words should evolve over time to be more efficient (shorter amount of time to say, write, etc.)

Comment: You would think that languages would evolve based solely on efficiency, but that's not really how languages work. There are other factors such as formality, politeness, cultural issues, and an element of random chance. It's the same reason why some languages have short, single words for concepts that take an entire sentence in another language. That said, one would expect yes/no to be more of a universal concept.

Comment: Bamileke languages of Cameroon generally have a disyllabic word for "no" with a form like [jVkV]. It's interesting since the languages have mostly mono- and disylalbic words.

Comment: @Parseltongue The problem is that other languages may use a more complex form (that is, more equivalent to English 'affirmative' and 'negative') as their 'default' way of saying 'yes' or 'no'. I think you need to re-cast your question along the lines I suggested above, ie asking about the largest **single morpheme** words for 'yes' and 'no'.

Comment: Must it be a single morpheme, or just the unmarked way to say yes and no?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut, sure we can recast the question as monomorphemic, although I don't understand why this is confusing.  In every language, babies learn a singular expression for yes/no first.  In Swahili, it's "ndiyo" and "hapana."  Are there languages with longer expressions than this?  Babies don't learn "affirmative" and "negative."  In any case, it's been 5 years with no answers.  I don't think I'll ever get an answer

Comment: What about English where the standard answer to a yes/no question is something like YesIDo/NoIDont?

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to point out that "no" in Swahili is *hapana*, not *hakuna*. Both are structurally identical, differing only in the class of the subject prefix. Class 16, with *pa-* generally refers to a precise location whereas *ku-*, class 17, refers to an imprecise location. *Hakuna* [ha-ku-na :: NEG-C17.SUBJ-COM] is used to mean "There isn't/aren't (a/any) ...". *Hapana* [ha-pa-na :: NEG-C16.SUBJ-COM] means "There isn't/aren't (a/any) ..." at a specific location.

***Hapa*** *hapana tembo.* = There isn't an elephant **(right) here**.
***Huku*** *hakuna tembo.* = There aren't any elephants **around here**.

*Hakuna* is likely to be used as "no" only after questions with *kuna* "is/are there"?

*Je, kuna tembo huku?* = Are there elephants around here?
*Hakuna.* = No, there aren't.

*Hapana* is possible with other sentence types.

Note, however, that in most discourse in English, people don't usually just answer with "yes" and "no". Of course it's possible, but it has a rather abrupt tone. We could regard English as having over 50 different ways to say "no", all of them around 3 or 4 syllables in length and agreeing with the subject, auxiliary verb and tense of the preceding question: *No, I'm not. No it didn't. No, we can't. No, there wasn't. No, they won't. No, it hasn't. No, you shouldn't. No, she doesn't.* ...

Another thing to note is that *ndiyo* is only two syllables. The *nd* is a single phoneme, a prenasalised voiced alveolar stop. The *y* also doesn't stand for a phoneme because /i.o/ and /i.jo/ are not distinguished in Swahili. For this reason, a lot of people misspell it as *ndio* (which is also a valid word). The difference between *ndio* and *ndiyo* is class agreement. *Ndio* uses a C2, C3, C11 or C14 morpheme *-o*, whereas *ndiyo* uses *-yo*, a C3, C6, or C9 morpheme. In environments after /a o u/, the difference between /jo/ and /o/ is clear (as in *mti unaOkua* "a tree that is growing" vs. *miti inaYOkua*), but not after /e/ or /i/. The spelling of *ndiyo* for "no" is based on the fact that it uses class 9 agreement and there is no rule for spelling change that makes this  drop in environments where it cannot be distinguished. So, phonemically, it's /ˈⁿdi.o/ — two simple open syllables, only one consonant.

I had a look through the translations for "no" on Wikipedia and didn't see anything longer than *hapana* as the only translation. There are things like *minimē* in Latin, which is as long, or longer owing to the long vowel, but there are shorter versions. If you don't accept "affirmative" and "negative" then I suppose you wouldn't accept *minimē*. I find it unlikely to find a longer word or phrase that you would accept because there are always likely to be shorter versions.

Even in Swahili, *hapana* is not the shortest way to say "no". That would be *la*. There is also *siyo* (again, with /j/ only distinguished in orthography, resulting in many spelling it as "sio"), which is the negative equivalent of *ndiyo*. *Hapana* is just the one that's widely used and widely taught, given as the most basic form.

Another thing to consider is that languages with simpler syllable structures and fewer phonemes tend to have higher syllable counts, but those syllables are, on average, uttered at a faster rate.

https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.aaw2594